# python aiogram Как сделать, чтобы бот отправлял галерею изображений, которую можно листать с помощью inline кнопок?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, inline

Бот должен отобрать из БД подходящие картинки и отправить их с помощью file_id.
Как сделать, чтобы он отправлял их по одной, а снизу были кнопки вперед/назад для перемещения по картинкам.
С помощью чего можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто, возьмём за пример базы данных обычный словарь:

```py
fruits = [
    {
        "slug": "apples",
        "display_name": "Яблоки",
        "image_url": "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/199/33/68/iStock-1158470655_d_850.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "oranges",
        "display_name": "Апельсины",
        "image_url": "https://www.gastronom.ru/binfiles/images/20141003/b3c0313e.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "bananas",
        "display_name": "Бананы",
        "image_url": "https://elorda.info/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/banana-health-big.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "lemons",
        "display_name": "Лимоны",
        "image_url": "https://ont.by/static/article/big/index/BWLqeb0F5qwrITqE.jpg"
    },
]
```

Для работы с Callback-данными можете использовать [фабрику коллбэков](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/buttons/#_5), это очень удобно.

```py
fruits_callback = CallbackData("Fruits", "page")
```

Затем, Вам нужна функция, которая будет создавать кнопки, в зависимости от страницы, которая была выбрана:

```py
def get_fruits_keyboard(page: int = 0) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    has_next_page = len(fruits) > page + 1

    if page != 0:
        keyboard.add(
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="< Назад",
                callback_data=fruits_callback.new(page=page - 1)
            )
        )

    keyboard.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=f"• {page + 1}",
            callback_data="dont_click_me"
        )
    )

    if has_next_page:
        keyboard.add(
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="Вперёд >",
                callback_data=fruits_callback.new(page=page + 1)
            )
        )

    return keyboard
```

Затем, можно сделать команду `/fruits`, которая будет выводить первую страницу (0 - для нашего словаря с фруктами, 1 - для пользователя)

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=["fruits"])
async def fruits_index(message: Message):
    fruit_data = fruits[0]
    caption = f"Вы выбрали <b>{fruit_data.get('display_name')}</b>"
    keyboard = get_fruits_keyboard()  # Page: 0

    await bot.send_photo(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        photo=fruit_data.get("image_url"),
        caption=caption,
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply_markup=keyboard
    )
```

Ну и конечно же, нам нужен Callback-хэндлер, который так же будет отображать данные нашей страницы, и строить клавиатуру пагинации:

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(fruits_callback.filter())
async def fruit_page_handler(query: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    page = int(callback_data.get("page"))

    fruit_data = fruits[page]
    caption = f"Вы выбрали <b>{fruit_data.get('display_name')}</b>"
    keyboard = get_fruits_keyboard(page)

    photo = InputMedia(type="photo", media=fruit_data.get("image_url"), caption=caption)

    await query.message.edit_media(photo, keyboard)
```

В итоге, весь наш код будет выглядеть так:

```py
fruits = [
    {
        "slug": "apples",
        "display_name": "Яблоки",
        "image_url": "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/199/33/68/iStock-1158470655_d_850.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "oranges",
        "display_name": "Апельсины",
        "image_url": "https://www.gastronom.ru/binfiles/images/20141003/b3c0313e.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "bananas",
        "display_name": "Бананы",
        "image_url": "https://elorda.info/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/banana-health-big.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "lemons",
        "display_name": "Лимоны",
        "image_url": "https://ont.by/static/article/big/index/BWLqeb0F5qwrITqE.jpg"
    },
]

fruits_callback = CallbackData("Fruits", "page")


def get_fruits_keyboard(page: int = 0) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    has_next_page = len(fruits) > page + 1

    if page != 0:
        keyboard.add(
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="< Назад",
                callback_data=fruits_callback.new(page=page - 1)
            )
        )

    keyboard.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=f"• {page + 1}",
            callback_data="dont_click_me"
        )
    )

    if has_next_page:
        keyboard.add(
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="Вперёд >",
                callback_data=fruits_callback.new(page=page + 1)
            )
        )

    return keyboard


@dp.message_handler(commands=["fruits"])
async def fruits_index(message: Message):
    fruit_data = fruits[0]
    caption = f"Вы выбрали <b>{fruit_data.get('display_name')}</b>"
    keyboard = get_fruits_keyboard()  # Page: 0

    await bot.send_photo(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        photo=fruit_data.get("image_url"),
        caption=caption,
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply_markup=keyboard
    )


@dp.callback_query_handler(fruits_callback.filter())
async def fruit_page_handler(query: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    page = int(callback_data.get("page"))

    fruit_data = fruits[page]
    caption = f"Вы выбрали <b>{fruit_data.get('display_name')}</b>"
    keyboard = get_fruits_keyboard(page)

    photo = InputMedia(type="photo", media=fruit_data.get("image_url"), caption=caption)

    await query.message.edit_media(photo, keyboard)
```